# My OnSucsess and OnFailure Listener isnt working

Tags: android, android-studio

So I want to grab the data from my Firestore db and put it into an arraylist with the objects I defined in an Actions.java file. 
The db reference is correct. 
The object in the db is correct. 
But the program skips BOTH the OnSucsess and OnFailure listeners. 
What could be causing that?

```
public class Activity_edit_actions extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference notebookRef = db.collection("actions");
    private ArrayList<Action> actionList = new ArrayList<Action>();
    List<Action> userActionsList;
    private ActionAdapter adapter;
    Context context = this;
    CollectionReference userDbRef = db.collection("users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()).collection("actions");
    CollectionReference dbRef = db.collection("actions");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_edit_actions);
    getUserActions();
    setUpRecyclerView();
}

private void setUpRecyclerView() {
    Query query = notebookRef.orderBy("priority", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Action> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Action>()
            .setQuery(query, Action.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new ActionAdapter(options, actionList);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}

public void addActionsToLocal(){
    TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);
}

public void getUserActions(){
    userDbRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                Action action = documentSnapshot.toObject(Action.class);
                actionList.add(action);
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d("redebug", "onFailure: Retrieving user actions from db failed");
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: How did you verify that `userDbRef.get()` is returning what you expected?

Comment: Well, I checked that the firestore db has the right stuff in the right order... 
I am noob, please can you explain a bit more what you mean?

Comment: Are you saying that you checked in your console that the values are correct? If that's the case, then your client setup in your app might be incorrect if your listener isn't firing.

Comment: Yes, I did check they are correct in the console. 
How can I debug and fix if my client in my app is incorrect?

Comment: Also please note that I tried the EXACT same code in another activity, and it worked perfectly. Its like it skips the code in the activity I gave above as well as in my FireStoreRecyclerAdapter class. 

Works everywhere else. Any idea what is wrong?